# Magento 2: Impossible to add new sizes

Tags: magento2

I've been trying to add new sizes or save changes and impossible to do.

here is movie:
temporarily removed

[image]

I have add here new sizes and then "save" after refresh page still empty field.

Comment: It good to give a video for demo or for reference  to understand actual problem,  but don't be open to show url of site specially admin url that might be a security cause. hope you got my point.  `max_input_vars`  limit is your concern as @simonthe share in his answer.

Comment: @Sylverster,  I show your website, i feel that is in under development i guess, but looking nice, i observed  and identified an issue that is `swatch-renderer.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: this._setPreSelectedGallery is not a function ` function is missing.

Comment: @Sylverster, I might be wrong to suggest you here in this public access plat-form but i feel we all here to listen and get good idea to make our website/application to very nice. **Whenever we are using form or input element try to keep unique ID for each input element, page level that will help us to make site without lot console error**

Comment: Kanhaiya thanks for your help and your suggest. I check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the virtual products, I think this happens when you add configurations to a configurable product, but don't specifiy a weight. Then the child products are added as "Virtual".

Regarding the sizes, please check your error logs. You have many values, and PHP has a setting max_input_vars that defaults to 1000. This settings means that in default, a form can have only 1000 fields, all fields above will not be received. If this is the error, you will see it in the webserver's error log, and can adjust that variable to your needs.